# Expo Speech resume and pause methods not working on Android - React Native

Tags: android, react-native, expo, react-native-ios

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Button } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import * as Speech from 'expo-speech';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  speak() {
    var thingToSay = 'Some Text here. I am writing this to test few features.';
    Speech.speak(thingToSay);
  }

  pausePlay(){
    Speech.pause();
  }
   
  resumePlay(){
    Speech.resume();
  }

  stopPlay(){
    Speech.stop();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button title="Press to hear some words" onPress={this.speak} />
        <Button title="Press to pause" onPress={this.pausePlay} />
        <Button title="Press to resume" onPress={this.resumePlay} />
        <Button title="Press to stop" onPress={this.stopPlay} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});
```

Expo Speech’s resume and pause methods are not working on the Android Platform. However they work just fine on the iOS Platform. I can’t move away from Expo. So is there a way I can use expo and still achieve the functionality, Kindly help.

Expo SDK Version: 37
Platforms(Android/iOS/web/all): Android

Comment: emulator or physical device?

Comment: and please post some code, so we can take a look.

Comment: Physical device. I can post the code but I am not sure how that is gonna help as Speech.resume or Speech.pause pretty much don't do anything on the Android Platform. However, the same code works fine on iOS. Also, I am referring to the below link that suggests these methods are not supported in Android  - https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/1192

Comment: Does anyone have any idea or a workaround?

Comment: Thats why i asked for the code, maybe you can try digging in the expo-speech repo and create your own pipe to disable'enable the voice

Comment: @forthelulx I have added the code. Can u help?

Comment: Right. I understand that but I don't want to move away from expo. I was hoping if there is some other workaround while I stick with expo...@forthelulx